# Propagators in position space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, fourier-transform, propagator

What are the possible applications of position-space representations of propagators? I'm speaking not only of the well-known free field case, but also of the particles in external fields and/or curved space-time. What might be the possible advantages to have such explicit position-space analytic formulas? What insights these formulas might give?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/299834/quantum-field-theory-in-position-space-instead-of-momentum-space). Further see [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Position_space).

Comment: A huge subject/cottage-industry. Decent review: Skenderis, K. (2002). Lecture notes on holographic renormalization. *Classical and Quantum Gravity* **19** (22), 5849.

Comment: Well, in the linked topic there is only a discussion of advantages of momentum-space representation, which is obvious. I'm interested in justifying the need to study position-space representations.